# Figure out the right command line value for IIS Express 8.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have a custom ASP.NET MVC 4 solution and I use IIS Express for hosting through Visual Studio (v2013). IIS Express hosts the application normally through Visual Studio, while the command line call starts the application, but all requests ends with 404 Error.

My sample command line call:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:"<path to my site>" /port:7888 /trace:e
```

...and the output for one request (the same requested Url works normally if run through VS):

```
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 548189463
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 548189463
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 548189463
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 548189463
Start listenerChannel http:0
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:7888/" for site "Development Web S
ite" application "/"
Registration completed
AppPool 'IISExpressAppPool' initialized
InitComplete event signalled
IncrementMessages called
Request started: "GET" http://localhost:7888/
Request ended: http://localhost:7888/ with HTTP status 404.0
```

I suppose it should work if I used the same command line as VS does. How can I figure out what VS does in the scenes behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holly bull, it's the path argument - it must be absolute, IIS Express doesn't work properly with a relative path.

Comment: If you used Process Explorer or Process Monitor to analyze how Visual Studio launches IIS Express, then you might notice that earlier.